# Why does AppDelegate inherit from UIResponder?

Tags: ios, uiresponder

I noticed that when creating a new project with the iPhone Master-Detail template in Xcode 4.2 beta 4, it does:

```
// AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Why does `AppDelegate` inherit from `UIResponder` instead of `NSObject`?

Comment: If you had to guess, what would you say?

Comment: @Caleb, [I'd guess it's a typo in Xcode 4.2 beta 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893221/why-does-appdelegate-inherit-from-uiresponder/6893476#6893476).

Comment: You might be right and I don't want to comment too much on something still under NDA, but that wouldn't be my guess.

Comment: One of its use is to continue handling returning of url from logging in via facebook or other applications ie. require authentication with-in the app.

Answer (score 14):

From [Converting to Storyboards Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/):

> Note: In the current Xcode templates, the application delegate class inherits from UIResponder. This is so that the delegate instance can participate in the responder chain and so handle application-level actions. If you haven’t made use of this pattern in an existing application, there’s no need to adopt it for storyboards.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation of `UIResponder`. Since AppDelegate can respond to touch events, it implements the `UIResponder` interface.

Answer (score 2):

[`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/) is the base class for the UIKit framework. `UIResponder` can deal with the events.

Your `AppDelegate` class is the delegate class for the [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) which [`UIApplicationMain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain) creates. `AppDelegate` conforms to the [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/) protocol.

The `UIResponder` class has the methods to get the window of the application focus  on which all the views will be populated, so you should have a class that inherits from `UIResponder` in order to make the window as key.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is so it has access to the global undo manager.

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate inherits from `UIResponder` that handles iOS events. The `UIResponder` class defines an interface for objects that respond to and handle events.

Answer (score -4):

UPDATE: My answer below might be wrong. I was just going by the image in the iOS documentation. But, it must be outdated.

Unless there's something new in iOS 5 and not yet documented, then I think this is a typo with this Xcode 4.2 beta 4 template. In an iOS app, the app delegate should subclass `NSObject`, not `UIResponder`, e.g.:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

For [iOS apps, in UIKit (for Cocoa Touch, e.g., iPhone & iPad), `UIApplication` is the last responder in the responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW5).

For [Mac OS X apps, in the Application Kit (for Cocoa, e.g., Mac), the app delegate is the last responder in the responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW9).